# Testing for the independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

In probability theory, $X$ and $Y$ are independent if:
$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

If I have sample $Y_1,...,Y_n$ and I would like to test if $Y_i$ is independent from the rest of the sample, I wonder if showing:

$ f_{Y_1|Y_2,...Y_n}(y_1|y_2,...,y_n)=f_{Y_1}(y_1)...f_{Y_n}(y_n) $,etc.., 
would be the right way to do or there will be another way to test for independence of random variable $Y$? ( I found it is hard to show the above condition if I dont know the distribution/density function

Thank you so much in advance for any recommendation.

Comment: Your very first formula is incorrect.  It should read $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y);$$ that is, the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ equals the product of their marginal densities.

Comment: Your first formula does not seem to have anything to do with your question. You seem to be asking about independent events vs independent random variables.

Comment: @user137481, amWhy, Surb You suggested or approved an edit of the title mentioning independent events. There are no independent events in the question. How comes?

Comment: OP: To check that $Y_1$ is independent from the rest, one would show that $$f_{Y_1\mid Y_2,\ldots,Y_n}(y_1\mid y_2,\ldots,y_n)=f_{Y_1}(y_1),$$ not what you wrote.

Comment: @Did In the question, the OP stated that he would "like to test if $Y_i$ is independent from the rest of the sample". If I interpret each $Y_i$ as for example, the result of a coin toss, it would appear that the OP is asking about how he could determine whether the coin tosses are independent.

Comment: @Did would you also be able to elaborate on independent events vs independent random variables? I'm sure a lot of students learning probability for the first time are confused. I know i am...   8-)

Comment: @user137481 With this reasoning, every question about random variables should mention "events" in their title... // Elaborate? Why not, but not on this page. If you have a specific question about the independence of events, just post it on the site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and pointing out my mistake. Yes, in order to show that $Y_i$ is independent random variable, I need to show that its conditional density function is its marginal density function and this is the step that I got stuck. For example if I have observations of 4 weekly return for January and I would like to test if those returns are independent. However, I found it hard to show the relationship between theirs conditional density function and their marginal density function